# MySQL utf8mb4 unicode (Smiles)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, unicode, utf8mb4

So, today i was faced with the problem:

SQL request:

```
INSERT INTO `sample` (`lol`) VALUES ('');
```

Response:

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x88' for column 'lol' at row 1
```

Collation:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
    +--------------------------+--------------------+
    | Variable_name            | Value              |
    +--------------------------+--------------------+
    | character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
    | character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
    | character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
    | character_set_filesystem | binary             |
    | character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
    | character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
    | character_set_system     | utf8               |
    | collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
    | collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
    | collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
    +--------------------------+--------------------+
    10 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

my.ini:

```
[client]
port=3306
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-server=utf8mb4
```

[MySQL Workbench Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNGEP.png)

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXnIz.png)

How to fix it?

Comment: What’s the table data structure?

Comment: [database structure](http://imgur.com/xei9FYd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple. You just need to do
`SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'`